# Copy cells to another cell when filled with color

Tags: excel

I was wondering if this is possible:

I have a row of data on column `A` and is it possible that when I highlight (fill) say `A1` in a color it will automatically copy/paste into `E1`?

Comment: Are you looking for a `VBA` solution or an In Cell Formula because this is possible for `VBA` but In Cell will not work as there is no access to this data in a Formula

Comment: Ye I would have thought it was VBA but I'm not very good at so if you could kindly help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a `VBA` solution this will work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static PrevCell As Range
    If Not PrevCell Is Nothing Then
        If PrevCell.Column = 1 Then
           If PrevCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
              PrevCell.Copy
              Paste Cells(PrevCell.Row, "E")
           Else
              'In case you unhighlight the cell
              Cells(PrevCell.Row, "E") = ""
              Cells(PrevCell.Row, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
           End IF
        End If
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set PrevCell = Target
End Sub
```

The assumption here is that all cells are using the standard fill of `xlNone` which means no fill. If you have cells that have other fill colors and you only want to capture when the cell is a certain color you will need to change it to

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static PrevCell As Range
    If Not PrevCell Is Nothing Then
        If PrevCell.Column = 1 Then
           If PrevCell.Interior.ColorIndex = INSERT PROPER HIGHLIGHTING COLOR INDEX HERE Then
             PrevCell.Copy
             Paste Cells(PrevCell.Row, "E")
           Else
              'In case you unhighlight the cell
              Cells(PrevCell.Row, "E") = ""
              Cells(PrevCell.Row, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
           End IF
        End If
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set PrevCell = Target
End Sub
```

**Update**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static PrevCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim lcell As Range
    If Not PrevCell Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If PrevCell.Column = 1 Then
            If PrevCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                PrevCell.Copy
                If Cells(LastRow, "E") <> "" Then
                    Paste Cells(LastRow + 1, "E")
                Else
                    Paste Cells(LastRow, "E")
                End If
            Else
                'In case you unhighlight the cell
                For Each lcell In Sheet1.Range("$E$1", "$E$" & LastRow)
                    If lcell.Value = PrevCell.Value Then
                        lcell.Delete xlShiftUp
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next lcell
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set PrevCell = Target
End Sub
```

Issues: Everytime you enter a highlighted cell it will append the value to the list. If you have duplicate values in Column A un-highlighting 1 will remove only 1 from the running list in E. If you do not have duplicates in column A then you would need to institute a loop over E to determine if the value already exists. Like so :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static PrevCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim lcell As Range
    Dim isDuplicate AS Boolean

    If Not PrevCell Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If PrevCell.Column = 1 Then
            If PrevCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                For Each lcell In Sheet1.Range("$E$1", "$E$" & LastRow)
                    If lcell.Value = PrevCell.Value Then
                        isDuplicate = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next lcell
                If Not isDuplicate Then
                    PrevCell.Copy
                    If Cells(LastRow, "E") <> "" Then
                        Paste Cells(LastRow + 1, "E")
                    Else
                        Paste Cells(LastRow, "E")
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                'In case you unhighlight the cell
                For Each lcell In Sheet1.Range("$E$1", "$E$" & LastRow)
                    If lcell.Value = PrevCell.Value Then
                        lcell.Delete xlShiftUp
                    End If
                Next lcell
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set PrevCell = Target
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, thats how I want it, but is it possible to also copy/paste the fill colour as well onto E1?

Comment: @user3562155 updated my answer to use `Copy` and `Paste` so that you maintain all formatting from the original cell

Comment: sorry to be a pain again, but can I change it so that if I highlight/fill any rows on column A, it will paste on E1 first then E2, E3 and so on?

Comment: You will have to explain a bit further for me to understand what you mean

Comment: for example, in column A I have a list of data, if I highlight (fill) any cell on column A it will paste onto E1 and so on, so e.g. if i highlight A10 it will paste onto E1 and next I highlight A3 it will paste onto E2 and so on.

Comment: @user3562155 Okay so there are some hang ups with your request. Since this just checks cell color and not if the color was changed items will be appended to the list every time you enter that highlighted cell. Also are there duplicates in Column A as this should be a constraint when removing the un-highlighted items. I have updated my answer with a description of the issues.

Comment: don't worry about it now, i managed to get it sorted, thanks anyway!